# Querying people with exact given friends

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows.

```
PersonId     FriendId
    p1        f1
    p1        f2
    p2        f1
    p2        f3
    p3        f1
    p4        f1
    p4        f2
```

I need to get all the people (PersonId) who have exactly (f1 and f2, for example. Could be any number of friends) as friends. What would be a good sql for this?
In the above example, i need to get the answer as

```
PersonId
    p1
    p4
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT PersonId FROM TableName WHERE FriendId IN (f1, f2)

Comment: @RomanKoliada that query will also give me p3 since it also satisfies the where condition. Even if a person has one of those friends he will be returned while i want the person with exactly those two friends.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/192134/1822

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks you for helping me. From this day I know that stackoverflow has many **everyone_except_me_know_underground_laws** like this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT personid
FROM table_name
WHERE friendid IN ('f1', 'f2')
GROUP BY personid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT friendid) = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use the following approach if it is not possible that there are two exactly the same rows.

```
select personId
from your_table
where friendId in ('f1', 'f2')
group by personId
having count(*) = 2
```

If it is possible to have two rows with the same `personId` and `friendId` then use `count(distinct friendId)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: Do not hesitate to express a reason for the downvote

Comment: Don't worry my friend. They are just **The crowd**, as in `Gustave Le Bon`'s book. Don't try to understand them. They're too crowded too dangerous.